# Python - How to store a socket and a username in a list?

Tags: python

Is there any way I can store a socket and a username in a list? I don't think this is possible, as an integer is required in the list to store the index. What would you guys recommend I do? Really have no idea.

Comment: Are you sure you want to put them in a list and not a dict?

Comment: Could you give an example of what you're trying to accomplish?  It isn't very clear from your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to store tuples in your list.

```
l = list()
l.add(tuple(username, socket))

print l[0][0], l[0][1] # will print username and soket of first item
```

Or you can define class, for example UserSock and fill up list with instances of this class

```
class UserSock:
    def __init__(self, username, socket):
        self.username = username
        self.socket = socket

l = list()
l.add(UserSock(username, socket))

print l[0].username l[0].socket # will print username and soket of first item
```

Comment: Note that `tuple(username, socket)` raises a TypeError -- you just use parentheses to create a tuple, like `(username, socket)`. Also, note that you can also use a [collections.namedtuple](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple), which has the advantage of being (almost) as fast and light as a tuple, but gives you the readability advantages of named accessors.